# React router not rendering the component on click of a Array item

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm creating a component which has array of items and showing them on one page using map function.
Need help on how I can show a detail view of a item by updating route value dynamically based on the item I clicked.
Currently when I click on a item know more though the url change to some wrong value I don't see any change in the page.

**Component**:

```
{location[area].map((item, index) =>
  <div key={index} className="col-md-4 mt-3">
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">{item.title}</h5>
        <p className="card-text">{item.description}</p>
        <Link to={'/view/${item.title}'} onClick={() => addDetail(item)} className="btn btn-primary">Know more</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)}
```

**Router:**

```
<Route path='/view/:id' exact component={DetailPage} />
```

**DetailPage Component:**

```
class DetailPage extends Component {
  render() {
    const selectedItem = this.props.selectedItem;
    return(
      <div>
        <DetailedView selectedItem={this.props.selectedItem}  />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Result Anchor Tag:**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/view/${item.title}">Know more</a>
```

**Onclick result url:**

```
http://localhost:3000/view/$%7Bitem.title%7D
```

Comment: Should use \` for template literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use backticks for the `to` prop of your `Link` components so that [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) will be used and the variable will be inserted into the string.

```
<Link
  to={`/view/${item.title}`}
  onClick={() => addDetail(item)}
  className="btn btn-primary"
>
  Know more
</Link>
```

Comment: Thanks Tholle.
Now I can see value being updated value in the anchor tag
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/view/2">Know more</a>
But onclick component  in not changing.
Once please refer to the above Router value as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well,As @tholle suggested use template literal.Your route seems fine, just make use of react life cycle method `componentWillReceiveProps` in the `Detail Page Component`.Here is the code

```
class DetailPage extends Component {
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
     if(this.props.match.params.id !== nextProps.match.params.id){
       //make a call with updated nextProps.match.id or filter the existing data store 
         with nextProps.match.id
      }
   }
  render() {
    const selectedItem = this.props.selectedItem;
    return(
      <div>
        <DetailedView selectedItem={this.props.selectedItem}  />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So here is the situation
In Detail page component I have **objectOfArrrays** as props, and from match params I have **id** and **array name**, so in WillReceiveProps method I need to have a logic of objectOfArray.arrayName[id].
Need help in syntaxing this correctly.
`const region = this.props.match.params.region;
 const propertyObj = this.props.properties;
const id = this.props.match.params.id;
<DetailedView data={this.props.selectedItem} />`

in the scenario of map function for different component I used 
`{propertyObj[region].map()}`